# fast way to update elements of a list comparing with another list

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, iteration

i got two Lists with integer IDs an old list and a new list.

Now i want to do three steps:
1. Check which IDs from (old)List1 are also found in (new)List2
2. Delete all elements from List1 that are not found in List2 after step 1
3. Add all missing IDs from List 2 to List 1

I was thinking of adding two boolean arrays and set a flag when an element was found, later i could delete the IDs elements from List1 and add the unchecked IDs from List2 in List1.

Maybe there are better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 6));
list1.retainAll(list2);
list2.removeAll(list1);
list1.addAll(list2);
System.out.println(list1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

put all content in a lookup table, for instance use a HashSet.